# Convert Hexadecimal to INT and vice versa

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, type-conversion

I will be creating a sequential Serial Number made from Hexadecimal values

With this Format:

```
XX-XX-XX-YYYY
Which XX-XX-XX is default value
And YYYY is the incrementing hexa decimal value
```

Now to create the serial number based on hex value I need Add 6 to the last generated hex value

```
MIN: 2D41 + 6 = 2D47    
     2D47 + 6 ... and so on
MAX: 4100   generation of serial will stop when I meet the MAX value.
```

I already created it in c# but I need to do it on SQL

```
int num1 = int.Parse("2D41", NumberStyles.HexNumber); //Convert hex to int
int result = num1 + 6; //Add + 6 for increment
string myHex = result.ToString("X");  //Convert result to hex
MessageBox.Show(myHex);  // result 2D47
```

How can this be done in T-SQL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope this helps you

```
declare @seed varchar(max) = '2D41';
declare @limit varchar(max) = '4100';

select convert(int, convert(varbinary(max), '0x'+@seed,1)),
       convert(int, convert(varbinary(max), '0x'+@limit,1));

;with seedlimit(seed, limit) as (
    select convert(int, convert(varbinary(max), '0x'+@seed,1)),
           convert(int, convert(varbinary(max), '0x'+@limit,1))
)
select SerialNumber = 'XX-XX-XX-' + right(convert(varchar(10),cast(s.seed + 6 * v.number as varbinary(max)),1),4)
from seedlimit s
join master.dbo.spt_values v on type='p'
where s.seed + 6 * v.number <= s.limit;
```

The basic ingredients are in there for you to create a view/procedure/function out of the answer,

Output:

```
SerialNumber
-------------
XX-XX-XX-2D41
XX-XX-XX-2D47
...
XX-XX-XX-40F7
XX-XX-XX-40FD
```

Answer (score 4):

```
DECLARE @x VARBINARY(8) = 0x00002D41;
SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), CONVERT(INT, @x) + 6);
```

In order to handle the output as a string:

```
DECLARE @x VARBINARY(8) = 0x00002D41;
SELECT CONVERT(CHAR(10), CONVERT(VARBINARY(8), CONVERT(INT, @x) + 6), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you already have it in C#, leave it there and simply convert your code to a SQL CLR function.

For a simple example see:

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/10/19/sql-server-introduction-to-clr-simple-example-of-clr-stored-procedure/

Comment: While true, seems overkill for a very simple pair of conversion operations.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Fair enough.  Your solution is definitely cleaner ;) +1